"One-time discount" fraud: is any crime committed?
A retailer offers a one time discount to new customers. The T&C clearly state that the discount is limited to one time per household.
However, Bob discovers that in practice he can just create new accounts on the retailer's website, and claim the discount for each new account he creates. He goes on to repeat that operation multiple times and claim thousands of dollars in repeated discounts before the retailer catches him.
I recognize that this could be considered fraud in a colloquial sense, or perhaps even a tortious non-criminal wrong.
But has any crime been committed? Are the elements of criminal fraud made out?
Interested in answers in the US. If state is important, let's say CA or WA.

In england-and-wales and northern-ireland, this would be fraud by misrepresentation under Section 2 of the Fraud Act 2006:

(1) A person is in breach of this section if he — (a) dishonestly
makes a false representation, and (b) intends, by making the
representation — (i) to make a gain for himself or another, or (ii) to
cause loss to another or to expose another to a risk of loss.
(2) A representation is false if — (a) it is untrue or misleading, and
(b) the person making it knows that it is, or might be, untrue or
misleading.
[...]
(4) A representation may be express or implied.

In your scenario, you make an implied representation that you are claiming the discount as a new customer. You do so dishonestly and the representation is false because you know it is untrue. Your intention in making it is to make a gain for yourself.

I've seen some sites explicitly specify eligibility requirements as e.g. "People who have not used ____ within the past ____ months/years", but not all sites make that clear.  If someone accepted a 30-day no-risk trial of a service and didn't like it, the providers of the service claim to have improved, and they don't specify what a "new customer" is, in what cases would the person be entitled to again accept a 30-day no-risk trial to see if the service had improved enough to be worth joining?

@supercat Contractual interpretation issues (e.g. meaning of "new customer") aren't important per se. What matters is what is in the mind of the customer when they do it. Phrases like "dishonestly makes", "intends", and "knows that it is" are all about state of mind. If you go for a 2nd 30-day trial and you don't believe you were representing anything untrue or misleading and/or you aren't acting dishonestly and/or you don't intend to make a gain then the offense isn't triggered. It doesn't matter if you did in fact make a gain or the representation was in fact false.

@JBentley: Even if the person didn't think they were making a false representation, the offense'd still be triggered if a person in the given situation would've been reasonably expected to know that what they were doing was making a false representation.

There was a similar case in the US. Long time ago when you linked a new account for inter-bank ACH transfers, banks would use tiny deposits (total less than a dollar) for you to confirm access to that account. They would transfer these deposits and leave them there. One young gentlemen from California opened tens of thousands of accounts and linked them to pocket thousands of dollars worth of such deposits. Another report (on indictment) here.
The young gentlemen was sentenced to 15 months in prison in a criminal case brought by the US attorney for computer fraud, which is the Federal statute violated here. There was also restitution to the banks involved. I don't know if there was a civil action on top of that.
The banks now don't let customers keep the tiny deposits, they withdraw them back from the linked accounts immediately.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
